# React UseEffect Not Rendering

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to do a simple render from state using useEffect but coming up blank, event though the useEffect is retrieving the data and twice! (although I only require it to render once and it won't get updated)..

**Json data file (extract) 'moviedetails.json':**

```
[
    {
        "Movie": {
            "RegionId": 1,
            "TitleId": 1,
            "Title": "13 Hours: The Secret Soldiers of Benghazi",
            "TitleYear": 2016,
            "Summary": "On Sept. 11, 2012, Islamic militants attack the U.S. Consulate in Benghazi, Libya, killing Ambassador J blah blah."
        },
        "Scenes": [
            {
                "SceneId": 2,
                "LocationSiteId": 108,
                "LocationPlaceName": "Valletta",
                "LocationSiteName": "Liesse Il-Belt",
                "Latitude": 35.89615,
                "Longitude": 14.5136
            },
            {
                "SceneId": 474,
                "LocationSiteId": 108,
                "LocationPlaceName": "Valletta",
                "LocationSiteName": "Liesse Il-Belt",
                "Latitude": 35.89615,
                "Longitude": 14.5136
            },
etc etc...
}
]
```

**And the js file...**

```
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Movies from '../data/moviedetails.json'

const MovieDetails = () => {

    const { id } = useParams()
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState([])       

    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (loadingMovie) {
            return
        }

     const filteredMovieDetails =   Movies.filter(moviedetail => moviedetail.Movie.TitleId == id)
             setMovie ( filteredMovieDetails )
        console.log ( filteredMovieDetails) // gets array but runs twice!              

    },[]);// Only needs to run once
    
    
    return (  

// RETURNS BLANK!   
        
        <Container> 
            <Row>

         <h1>{movie.Title}</h1>        
        </Row>            
         
       <Row>        
        <article>
           {movie.Summary}
        </article>
        </Row>      
                  
        </Container>
    )
}
export default MovieDetails;
```

At this stage I simply want to show the movie.Title and movie.Summary
Nothing is returned although state 'movies' has the correct data. I assume that is has something to do with the 'async' and the useEffect is running AFTER the return statement?

Comment: Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates?  At a glance it looks like you've simply confused yourself between what is an array and what is a single object.  Consistent use of pluralization in names is important.

Answer (score 2):

Your state value is an array:

```
const [movie, setMovie] = useState([])
```

So this won't render anything:

```
<h1>{movie.Title}</h1>
```

Because an array *has no* `Title` property.

---

If you expect the result to be an array, render the elements of that array:

```
return (
  <>
    {movie.map(m => (
      <Container> 
        <Row>
          <h1>{m.Title}</h1>        
        </Row>            
        <Row>        
          <article>
           {m.Summary}
          </article>
        </Row>      
      </Container>
    ))}
  </>
);
```

**And** rename your variable(s) to be **plural** so it's obvious that it's an array.

---

Alternatively, if you expect it to be *a single object*, change it to an object:

```
const [movie, setMovie] = useState();
```

And update it to an object:

```
const filteredMovieDetails = Movies.find(moviedetail => moviedetail.Movie.TitleId == id);
```

And conditionally render the object only when there is one to render:

```
return (
  {
    movie ?
      <Container> 
        <Row>
          <h1>{movie.Title}</h1>        
        </Row>            
        <Row>        
          <article>
           {movie.Summary}
          </article>
        </Row>      
      </Container> :
      <Container>No movie found!</Container>
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I'm using the 'array option' but now getting the following error....
"Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop"
I have tried adding 'TitleId' as the key at each tag and a div but I assume the error is coming from the 'Scenes' so I have also tried m.Scenes.SceneId.
It's basically a classic 'Master/ detail '  page (Scenes (detail) will be added after I fix the movie (master) part). Do you think it would be better to use two separate json files for master and detail?

Comment: @KevinM: I suspect in this case (at least for the `.map()` shown here) the only element that needs the `key` is `<Container>`.  If we're just iterating over "movies" then whatever unique identifier for a movie should work.  From the data I suspect that's `TitleId` but you can confirm in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Manage to sort it.  I needed a second 'map' function for the 'detail'...

```
return (
        <>
          {/* 'Master' */}
           {movie.map((m) => {            
            return(               
               <Container key={m.TitleId}>
                 <h2>{m.Title}</h2>     

                   {/* 'Detail' */}
                 {m.Scenes.map((s) => {
                  return (
                     <row key={s.SceneId}>
                         { s.LocationSiteName }
                        </row>
                        );
                     })}         
                    
                   </Container>
                 );
               })}
             </>
           );  

   @David : Thanks again for your help
```